# What datatype should I use in MySQL to store XSD formatted datetimes?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, datetime-format, type-conversion

I'm on the fence about these two options I've been considering:

**Option A:**    Using a `DATETIME` field and converting it to the xsd format after pulling it from the field

**Option B:**    Using a `VARCHAR` field and converting it to the xsd format before inserting it into the field

Maybe both options are equally as efficient, but maybe there is an Option C that I haven't considered yet.

If it makes a difference, its a requirement for a table that I'm making.  The data definition for the field reads:

`A date in xsd:dateTime format:  [-]CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]`

Example:  `2001-10-26T21:32:52`

I'm going to be using php to both read & write from this database and I know there are a plethora of date/time functions for both mysql and php alike.

What's the best datatype and method of read/write to use in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you need to do with that column, and what you are getting into it.

For example if you have to manipulate the value in a query then a `DATETIME` looks good, but then if you need to output it back to XSD, is the information in the time zone relevant? For even if you read it correctly with `CONVERT_TZ()`, the datetime column will lose you that information.

So if you need the "point in time", convert to UTC and store it as a datetime. If you also need to regenerate it identically, store the TZ in a secondary column.

If you do nothing with the information, then keep it as `VARCHAR` - you'll still be able to change idea down the line. The "datetime column only" is the only choice you won't be able to walk away from.

Comment: thanks, makes sense.... also, didn't know about the TZ info being destroyed with regards to `DATETIME` data type conversions. thanks for that info too